# How do I  insert an image on my disk into a database table?

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have an image on my filesystem and I want to update it in the database using Ruby.

I am using ActiveRecord for this purpose.

Example code:

```
table.picture = File.open("Imagefilepath", "r+").read()
```

I can see a blob entry in my database table but when I try to read the files from the DB all the images are corrupted.

Comment: I would strongly suggest against using DB for file storage in this way. Look into paperclip or similar...

Comment: Are you on Windows, or another OS? And what version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: am using windows and ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `"b"` option:

```
table.picture = open("Imagefilepath", "rb") {|io| io.read }
```

Or, if you're on ruby 1.9, you can use Symbol#to_proc:

```
table.picture = open("Imagefilepath", "rb", &:read)
```